# Apache 2.4 on windows crashing continously

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I'm using the latest XAMPP with with PHP 7.1.8 on Windows 10 Pro.
At a moment's notice the included apache server started to produce the following errors. Reinstalling, restarting, trying different versions of xampp, searching the web, nothing helps. It keeps on restarting... Same Problem with Installation of WAMP.

```
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:09.275015 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 13424 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:09.351715 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:09.351715 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:09.352216 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:09.362746 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16784
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:10.013977 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16784:tid 724] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:18.699169 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 16784 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:18.785521 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:18.785521 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:18.785521 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:18.796155 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8612
[Thu Sep 14 09:58:19.343273 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8612:tid 676] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:22.489254 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 8612 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:22.560254 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:22.560756 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:22.560756 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:22.571750 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12896
[Thu Sep 14 09:59:23.129289 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12896:tid 700] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:06.956424 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 12896 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:07.057701 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:07.058201 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:07.058201 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:07.077759 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17708
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:07.676408 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17708:tid 732] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.008406 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 17708 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.085799 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.085799 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.085799 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.097002 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3592
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:14.670296 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3592:tid 684] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:38.818171 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 3592 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:38.893039 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:38.893039 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:38.893039 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:38.905073 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17056
[Thu Sep 14 10:00:39.587701 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17056:tid 692] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:22.737788 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 17056 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:22.889690 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:22.890191 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:22.890191 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:22.906235 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 17636
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:23.582065 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 17636:tid 692] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:34.822440 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 17636 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:34.956772 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:34.956772 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:34.956772 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:34.969807 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12384
[Thu Sep 14 10:01:35.632841 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12384:tid 540] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:43.719692 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 12384 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:43.802796 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:43.802796 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:43.802796 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:43.816878 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6380
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:44.383000 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6380:tid 688] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:46.833877 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 6380 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:46.996185 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:46.996185 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:46.996185 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:47.012227 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 13728
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:47.711441 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13728:tid 728] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:50.675777 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00428: Parent: child process 13728 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:50.755284 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) PHP/7.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:50.755284 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:50.755284 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:50.769128 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11268:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 13488
[Thu Sep 14 10:02:51.319194 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13488:tid 684] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

From Windows Eventlog:

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: httpd.exe, Version: 2.4.25.0, Zeitstempel: 0x585506f4
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: ntdll.dll, Version: 10.0.15063.608, Zeitstempel: 0x802f667e
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000374
Fehleroffset: 0x000d9aba
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x21b0
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d32d5344cc158d
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Berichtskennung: a4b863c5-1ad2-4b08-ac54-36767303cc69
Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets: 
Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:
```